# how to query like for more than one keyword

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, model

i have a query to search content table to find rows with some keywords.(codeigniter)

i have a column to store keywords(the name of provinces).

i have a main province and related provinces that i should search them.

i have an array of keywords and its not clear that how many indexes it have.

so how can i search the content with multiple keywords

this is my query in model

```
public function province($province_name,$provinces_name,$language)
{
    $ps_name = str_replace("-", " ", $provinces_name);
    $lang=$language;

    $data = $this->db
                 ->select('*')
                 ->from('content')
                 ->where("language",$lang)
                 ->where("keywords",$province_name)
                 ->or_like("keywords","%$ps_name%")
                 ->limit("14")
                 ->order_by("id","DESC")
                 ->get();

    if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
        return $data->result();
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of keywords and you want each keyword to be searched at once, you can use **`$this->db->or_like()`** in a loop. Try code below:

```
$keywords = array("keyword1",
                  "keyword2",
                  "keyword3",
             );

foreach($keywords as $k)
{
    $this->db->or_like("keywords", $k);
}

$this->db->where("language", $lang);
$this->db->limit("14");
$this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
$query = $this->db->get("content");
```

Comment: but how can i use foreach into query ?

Comment: ->select('*')      ->from('noor_content')      foreach($provinces_name as $k)
{
                                                   ->or_like("keywords", $k);
}
      ->where("language",$lang)
                                                ->where("keywords",$province_name)
                                                
->limit("14")
      ->order_by("id","DESC")
     
->get();

Comment: Currently you are using chaining method to build query. You can break your query as I have done above. Looping through `or_like` will create a chain of `or_like-wildcards-keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about CI specific implementation, but if you're doing a search-like function with multiple keywords you can take a look at [MySQL's full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) (for InnoDB or MyIASM). Or a pretty good tutorial [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/03/04/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-2-the-queries/).